# Get data JsonArray and JsonObject via $.each Jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I have this, data json create from laravel API

```
[
    [{
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Customer-izlgy",
        "email": "ycgjl@xxyin.com"
    }, {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Customer-bkxjn",
        "email": "wlrew@iloiv.com"
    }],
    [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Customer-izlgyt",
        "email": "ycgjl@xxysdin.com"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Customer-bkxjnyf",
        "email": "wlrew@iloifsv.com"
    }]
]
```

I trying to get data id 4 and and id 1 via ajax, but always error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined**

This is my code to get name from above data json.

```
// get customer data that has been handled
function callHandledCustomer() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: rootUrl + "/api/chat/getHandledCustomer",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){
      $.each(response, function(i, customer) {
        console.log(customer[0][0].name); // get name
      });
    }

  });
}
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to remove your second `[0]` that doesn't match your object layout.

```js
var response = [
    [{
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Customer-izlgy",
        "email": "ycgjl@xxyin.com"
    }, {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Customer-bkxjn",
        "email": "wlrew@iloiv.com"
    }],
    [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Customer-izlgyt",
        "email": "ycgjl@xxysdin.com"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Customer-bkxjnyf",
        "email": "wlrew@iloifsv.com"
    }]
];

$.each(response, function(index, customer){
  console.log(customer[0].name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```